# How to print a result depends on String value?

Tags: java, syntax

I am very new to Java and would ask you for help.
I have this:

```
public class Person {

String name;
String gender;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person person = new Person();
    person.name("Max");
    person.gender = "male";
    
    Person person2 = new Person();
    person2.name = "Lea";
    person2.gender = "female";
}
```

What should be the correct syntax for the following method? Should I convert String to boolean?

```
if (String = male) {
    System.out.println("You are man!")
} else{
    System.out.println("You are woman!")
```

Thank you!

Comment: `String = male` is not likely to get compiled...

Comment: `if (gender.equals("male")) { ... }`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if (String = male)` is not valid syntax and won't even compile. You need to access the field, you need to compare it to a string (male is not a string, "male" is), `=` assigns a value but you want to compare for equality... If you are ever tempted to compare strings with `==` don't. String comparisons are done with the `equals()` method. And if you are going to compare a variable with a constant string value, call equals on the constant string value, because the variable can be null and you don't want to trigger a `NullPointerException`. So, to sum up: `if ("male".equals(myPerson.gender))`, assuming the `gender` field is accessible.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way would be

```
if (person.gender.equals("male")) {
    System.out.println("You are man!")
} else{
    System.out.println("You are woman!")
}
```

Where you can replace the String with the variable you would like to compare.